# Reassigning slice of Pandas column after modifying values

Tags: python, pandas

I need to perform the following operations in a loop: Select a slice of a pandas dataframe, then modify values of the slice (specifically, winsorize the data), then write the modified values back to the slice. What is the best practice for this? I have tried several ways, but the resulting column is usually full of NaNs.

```
for value in list_values:
    temp_df = df.loc[df["Column_a" == value]]
    transformed_data = pd.Series(mstats.winsorize(temp_df["Column_b"], limits=[0.05, 0.05])
    df.loc[df["Column_a" == value, "Column_b]] = transformed_data
```

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093241/how-to-replace-part-of-dataframe-in-pandas) might be of some help

Comment: @ShaikhAbuzar - Thanks, although these solutions are all used to combine dataframes, and I am trying to assign a series to a slice of a dataframe (the series has the same length as the dataframe slice). I have tried several suggestions there and was not succesful; any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think pandas.DataFrame.combine_first or pandas.DataFrame.update should solve this issue.
There are examples here
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: Thank you, although these functions seem to be used to combine two dataframes (or update based on another dataframe). Since I am trying to assign a series to a slice of a dataframe (the series has the same length as the dataframe slice), I have tried with those and have not been successful. Could you give me an example of how I could make my code work? I appreciate it!

Comment: There is an example here with a series. Maybe you can try it https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html